# Type of clusters in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

how can i differentiate hadoop standalone mode & pseudo distributed mode? Can anyone explain difference between all hadoop daemons as a single java process and separate java process

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between single node & pseudo-distributed mode in Hadoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23435333/what-is-the-difference-between-single-node-pseudo-distributed-mode-in-hadoop)

Comment: In both modes, there are separate Java processes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hadoop standalone mode is running Hadoop commands without starting Hadoop daemons i.e. on local file system.

The pseudo distributed mode is running Hadoop daemons on a single machine.

Comment: Hi, what if my hadoop installed via ambari? what is my hadoop's mode?